# Bind listview image source to image (Sqlite/ UWP/ C#)

Tags: c#, image, sqlite, listview, uwp

The following code can add images from a database to a listview, however I would like to bind the image property to the pictures in XAML using Image Source rather than use listview1.Items.Add. Can this code be easily modified to do this or do I have to go about this another way. Hopefully this isn't a stupid question to ask and I would appreciate any help.

```
public async void showImage()
    {
        var query = GetAll();

        foreach (var stuff in query)
        {
            string FileName;
            FileName = stuff.RecipeImage;
            var file = await
            Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

            Image ctrlImage = new Image();
            ctrlImage.Source = bitmapImage;
            ctrlImage.Height = 50;
            ctrlImage.Width = 50;
            ctrlImage.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;

            listView1.Items.Add(ctrlImage);
        }
    }
```

I need to add the image to the item source that is already used for my database which contains:

```
public class AddRecipe
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public string RecipeImage { get; set; }
} 

 <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="493" Margin="725,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="528" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" ItemClick="listView_SelectionChanged" FontSize="26.667">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="4">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecipeName}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MealType}" Foreground="Black"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ListView.ItemTemplate` to set the `DataTemplate` used to display each item and put all the images into a `ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>` as `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`. Then in `DataTemplate`, we can use `Bind` to set the `Image.Source`. Following is a simple sample:

In XAML, set `DataTemplate` with `{x:Bind}` to show image.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ImgList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
            <Image Width="50"
                   Height="50"
                   Source="{x:Bind }"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`ImgList` is defined in code-behind, it's defined as `ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>`, so the `DataType` of `DataTemplate` is `BitmapImage` and as I just bind the whole `BitmapImage` object to `Image.Source` so here just use `Source="{x:Bind }"`.

The code-behind may like following:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> ImgList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        showImage();
    }

    public async void showImage()
    {
        var query = GetAll();

        foreach (var stuff in query)
        {
            string FileName = stuff.RecipeImage;
            var file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

            ImgList.Add(bitmapImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Besides, I noticed that you are getting images form Pictures Library. If these images are stored by your app earlier, then storing them in app data would be better as this makes the binding easier and in Pictures Library, these images could be easily deleted by users.

To store images in app data, we can using `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to retrieve app's local data folder. For example, copy selected image into local data folder:

```
//This method copies selected image into local data folder and returns new file's name.
public async Task<string> CopySelectedImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var newCopy = await file.CopyAsync(localFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        return newCopy.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then we can using code like following to retrieve the image and create the `BitmapImage`:

```
var path = await CopySelectedImage();
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"ms-appdata:///local/{path}"));
```

**Update:**

I suppose you have had `RecipeImage` in your item source, then you can add a `Image` control into your `DataTemplate` and bind `RecipeImage` to it's `Source` with a `ImageConverter` like following:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="4" Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding RecipeName}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding MealType}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Image Width="50"
                   Height="50"
                   Source="{Binding RecipeImage,
                                    Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
                   Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

`ImageConverter` is used to convert `string` to `BitmapImage` as your `RecipeImage` is defined as `string` but `Image.Source` need a `BitmapImage`. Before using it in `Binding`, we need set it as a `StaticResource` firstly:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

The code of `ImageConverter` may like:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string FileName = value as string;
        var file = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(FileName).AsTask().Result;
        var stream = file.OpenReadAsync().AsTask().Result;
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        return bitmapImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which does show the images in a listview, however by adding the itemsource to ImgList it now doesn't show the name of the item in the list as it was binded to a database such as <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecipeName}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </StackPanel>, do you have any idea how i could have both showing together? Thanks

Comment: @myf33tsmell, you have no need to use `ImgList` since you have had a item source. You can use your item source (suppose it contains `RecipeImage`) with a value converter to show the image together with others. I updated my answer to show how to do this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Its working, it seems simple now but thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
xaml

<ListView Name="listView1">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="50" Width="50" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

и в коде добавляем List<BitmapImage>

List<BitmapImage> data_list = new List<BitmapImage>();

foreach (var stuff in query)
        {
            string FileName;
            FileName = stuff.RecipeImage;
            var file = await
            Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage;
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            }

          data_list.Add(bitmapImage);
        }

 listView1.ItemsSource = data_list;
```

then we just fill in the data into our ListView